# Calling a python script through Ajax to write to Excel

Tags: python, ajax, django, xlsxwriter

I'm using a Django web application, and I'm trying to export some data to excel automatically through Ajax. Right now I have a button in one of my templates that's bound to an Ajax function call when the user clicks it. That Ajax function calls a python script I wrote which uses the xlsxwriter python library to write out to excel. The script works locally on my machine, but doesn't save anything on the web app.

Here's the function from my ajax.py file:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from hipercic.apps.NeuroCiC import models
from django.core.files import storage
import file_analysis
import sys

@dajaxice_register
def export_excel_file(request, id):
  print 'TRIAL ID', id

  try:
    trial = models.Trial.objects.get(pk=id)
  except:
    'Could not find trial'
  else:
    print 'Found trial'
    SE_loc = trial.spikes_file.url
    VT_loc = trial.led_file.url
    print(SE_loc)
    print(VT_loc)
    return simplejson.dumps({'scatter_data': file_analysis.exportHistoExcel("test.xlsx") })
  return
```

And here's my python script (file_analysis.py):

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
def exportHistoExcel(SE_filelocation, VTfile_location, filename):

  print('anything?')

  data = getFiringRates(SE_filelocation, VTfile_location, generating_excel_file = True)
  print(data)

  print 'Writing to a new Excel file...'

  workbook = Workbook(filename)
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
  worksheet.write('A1', 'Bin (degrees)')
  worksheet.write('B1', '# of Spikes')
  worksheet.write('C1', '# of Samples')
  worksheet.write('D1', 'Time (sec)')
  worksheet.write('E1', 'Firing Rate')

  worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
  worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
  worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])
  worksheet.write_column('D2', data[3])
  worksheet.write_column('E2', data[4])
  worksheet.write('A62', 360); worksheet.write('B62', '=$B$2')
  worksheet.write('C62', '=$C$2'); worksheet.write('D62', '=$D$2'); worksheet.write('E62', '=$E$2')


  histo = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
  histo.set_title({'name': 'Firing Rates'})
  histo.set_x_axis({'name': 'Bin (degrees)'})
  histo.set_y_axis({'name': 'Firing rate (sec^-1)'})
  histo.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$E$2:$E$61',
                  'line': {'color': 'black'},
                 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$61'})
  histo.set_legend({'delete_series': [0]})
  worksheet.insert_chart('F2', histo)

  print 'Excel file written'


  workbook.close()

  print 'workbook closed'
```

All of the print statements are working, but when I check the directory to see if test.xls has been written, nothing is there.

Comment: First guess would be that file system permissions and/or selinux permissions are preventing the file access. However, I'd have expected an exception to be raised.

Comment: try to write it into /tmp, let's say under /tmp/test.xlsx or try to call before close() also save(filename).